# Find all broken urls and references in a LaTex document with footnote urls and bibtex urls

Tags: bibtex, footnotes

Is there some automated way to test broken urls over a LaTex document for errors such as 404 etc. I noticed that some broken urls but the list of reference is too massive to go through one-by-one. Ideas how to solve this kind quality control problem fast?

I have some ideas to solve this:

1. open up writing-process like in SO, with watchful peers, bugs tend become shallow
2. some at least partly automated processing of the document, perhaps something like apache-logging or something in that degree? (this is mere speculation and I have no idea how this could be done for a LaTex document to find and process broken material -- perhaps breaking up the large document into some blog series for peer-review where anyone can comment but it may become a larger problem of data-management)
3. other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same problem I just used the following scripts.  Sure some Perl hacker can make it a one-liner ;-). The first extract all explicit URLs (`\url{...}` from `.tex` and `url = {...}` from `.bib`.  I called it as `extractlinks.pl *.tex *.bib | sort | uniq > urls.txt` to get a list of URLs in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    foreach my $line (read_file($file)) {
        my @urls = ($file =~ /\.bib$/)
            ? $line =~ m/^\s*url\s*=\s*{([^}]+)}/
            : $line =~ m/\\url{([^}]+)}/g;
        print "$_\n" for @urls;
    }
}
```

The second script tries to download each URL with `wget`. On success the URL is printed to STDOUT, on failure it is printed to STDERR. I called the script as
`./checklinks.sh < urls.txt > url-ok.txt 2> url-fail.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url; do
    wget -O/dev/null -q "$url"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $url
    else 
        echo $url 1>&2
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If your URLs are consistently marked up, eg as `\url{...}` then it should be easy to extract a full list of them either just using sed or something or redefining \url to write them out. Given such a list it is easy to check all the url link to available documents, you could just use a command line tool like  wget or an online link checker like http://validator.w3.org/checklink

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to do this (no coding required) was to export my `.tex` file to PDF, and then use an excellent tool named [pdfx](https://www.metachris.com/pdfx/) to scan the PDF for broken links. Github link [here](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx).

Worked 'out-of-the-box' for me. Just two easy steps (assuming you already have python and pip installed).

```
$ pip install pdfx
$ pdfx <mydocument.pdf> -c
```

I tried it on my CV, which has more than 90 different links in the form of `\href{}{}` and plain-text. This tool detected them all. And, sure enough, it found some dead ones, which I promptly proceeded to replace.

Comment: does not work for multiline hyperlinks